# Cygwin git ssh to remote hangs

Tags: windows, git, ssh, cygwin, git-push

I'm occuring a weird error running on my Windows 7 64bit system with Cygwin (latest one from their homepage) installed including ssh-agent etc. and separately the msysgit. (Cygwin terminal: `git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0`)

When I try to push a git repo via Cygwin through a vpn tunnel it freezes at this position with the cursor just blinking:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git push live staging --verbose
trace: built-in: git 'push' 'live' 'staging' '--verbose'
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'user@my-server.com' 'git-receive-pack '\''/home/remote/example.git'\'''
Pushing to user@my-server.com:/home/user/my-server.git
```

1. First I thought there is a problem with my ssh key. But if I'm connecting directly to the server in Cygwin via `ssh user@my-server.com` it just asks for the passphrase and I'm in.
2. If I'm running only `ssh 'user@my-server.com' 'git-receive-pack '\''/home/remote/example.git'\'''` I see all the git branches/versions etc.
3. Lastly I tried to run the command `git push live staging` in the mysysgit directly and it worked.

But why it's not working via Cygwin?
Any thoughts or hints how I can debug the *freezing process* in Cygwin or what I've missed out?