# Unable to sync GitHub repo with local repo

Tags: git, github

I have a GitHub account that I am now unable to sync with my local repo.

Each time I try to push/pull/fetch changes to the repo, the `ssh` client just returns without printing any error messages and definitely without pushing the changes to the remote repo.

As an example:

```
$git push origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/home/sriram/.ssh/id_rsa':

sriramshankar@EHSriram /cygdrive/i/work/workspace/myProject
```

This is the output observed on a `Cygwin` terminal. Can anyone help me out with resolving this issue?

UPDATE:
I tried implementing more traces. It seems I am authenticated to the server but then it just abruptly stops:

```
$ GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git push origin master
OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.123] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/sriramshankar/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sriramshankar/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sriramshankar/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sriramshankar/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sriramshankar/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sriramshankar/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sriramshankar/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sriramshankar/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/sriramshankar/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/sriramshankar/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
Enter passphrase for key '/home/sriramshankar/.ssh/id_rsa':
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([192.30.252.123]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending command: git-receive-pack 'englishhelper/EHCloud.git'

sriramshankar@EHSriram /cygdrive/i/work/workspace/ehCloud
$ debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2808, received 2088 bytes, in 2.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 1379.3, received 1025.7
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Comment: What version of git are you using.

Comment: I am using `git version 2.8.2`

Comment: https://github.com/englishhelper/EHCloud does not exist though

Comment: It does. It is a private repo.

Comment: @VonC: Funny thing is, I am seeing this issue for every single repo I own. Might it have something to do with global config settings?

Comment: OK, I suppose this is cygwin related.try in a git bash or in a classic CMS session.

Comment: @VonC: That was the issue. Committing etc. works well from within the Git Bash shell but not cygwin. Any ideas on where I should look for what went wrong?

Comment: Not sure: Cygwin should not be needed here. Git bash itself comes with 400+ Linux commands (that you can even use from a regular CMD shell).

Comment: The issue was reported before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28190018/6309. Maybe an ssh config issue? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20627106/6309

Answer (score 3):

Start by:

- making sure your passphrase is [added to the ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent)
- [test your ssh connection to GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/):

  ```
  ssh -T git@github.com
  # more details:
  ssh -Tv git@github.com
  ```

You can [have more traces](https://askubuntu.com/q/336907/5470) with:

```
GIT_TRACE_PACKET=true git push
# or
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git push
```

The [OP Sriram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350685/sriram) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37917081/unable-to-sync-github-repo-with-local-repo?noredirect=1#comment63374681_37917081):

> That was the issue. Committing etc. works well from within the Git Bash shell but not cygwin.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can see (please see update to question for more details) with traces on that the server authenticates me but then just terminates the connection..

Comment: How do I enable more traces method using Git Bash? Git Bash opens in the Windows Power Shell for me.

Comment: No it does not, it opens abash shell

Comment: @Sriram Go to `C:\path\to\git\PortableGit-2.9.0-64-bit\bin` and type `bash --login -i`: you will get a GNU bash, version 4.3.42(5)-release.